# Matriz de penalização nos modelos aditivos generalizados com suavização por meio de P-splines

Tags: r, sas

Estou estudando os modelos aditivos generalizados usando o pacote `MGCV` do `R`. Abaixo segue um exemplo ilustrativo para um determinado ajuste usando a função gam.

```
library(mgcv)


data(mcycle)

attach(mcycle)

mod_gam <- gam(accel ~ s(times, bs="ps", k = 7,m=c(2,2)), knots = list(knots),data = mcycle)
```

Esta função usa para o ajuste algumas quantidades. Dentre elas está a matriz de penalização obtida da seguinte maneira:

```
S <- mod_gam$smooth[[1]]$S

Segundo o livro do Wood, esta matriz é construída da seguinte maneira:

library (splines)


knots <- mod_gam$smooth[[1]]$knots

X <- splineDesign(knots = knots, times)

C <- rep(1, nrow(X)) %*% X

qrc <- qr(t(C))

Z <- qr.Q(qrc,complete=TRUE)[,(nrow(C)+1):ncol(C)]

XZ <- X%*%Z

D<-mod_gam$smooth[[1]]$D

S2<-t(Z)%*%t(D)%*%D%*%Z
```

Contudo, elas diferem. Alguém saberia me dizer o que poderia estar acontecendo?